# How can I stop my crypto library from using an initialization vector?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptojs, sjcl

I'm trying to use the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (link below) to encrypt some data, which uses a randomly generated initialization vector during the encryption process so that two identical inputs will never produce the same outputs. Unfortunately, my project requires that two identical inputs *do* produce the same output, so I can't use initialization vectors. Is there an option or a way to modify the SJCL code so that it doesn't use IVs?

I've also been considering CryptoJS, another library, so if anyone knows a way to disable IVs in CryptoJS, that'd work too.

SJCL documentation: http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

CryptoJS on Github: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: SJCL would fail horribly if you would force a static IV because of many-time pad problems due to the use of CCM mode. This seems like an XY-problem. Can you describe why you can't have random IVs? In CryptoJS, you can freely choose the IV, so I don't see an issue there.

Comment: My problem is that I have to check the encrypted password I generate against the encrypted password in the database (for a username/password login system), so I can't have the encrypted strings changing every time I send them. The obvious solution is to have the database decrypt the strings to see if they match, but my colleague is in charge of programming the database, and he doesn't have enough PHP expertise to do it and I don't have enough time to help him out. I'll try CryptoJS.

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523) In PHP, you can use `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: Passwords are never encrypted or hashed in the browser. They are always transmitted through https to the server where they are hashed.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I'll check out those links.